# Sharepoint, how to link image to Fom

Tags: list-form

Im trying to do this but I don't know if that is even possible. I have a normal list with that "Add new item" to open a form, is it possible to have an image with a hyperlink that when clicked open the form automatically without the need of changing the page to that particular list

Comment: I want that when the user clicks on the image automatically open the from

Comment: Please give your question a more descriptive title, the title you have now is not really describing your issue

Answer (score 0):

Did you want to create a hyperlink to the "Add New Item" form? In that case you can do so by using the following URL:

```
{url1}/NewForm.aspx?Source={url2}
```

Where URL1 is the url to your site, and url2 is url where you want to redirect the user to after they finished adding a new item.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SP.UI.ModalDialog in javascript to open the form in a dialog box. Or you can link directly to the newform.aspx page, if you don't care about it opening in a new page instead of a dialog box.